# How to address security vulnerabilities: LUCKY13, BEAST, and BREACH

Tags: security

A client sent in an urgent request to resolve 3 vulnerabilities: LUCKY13, BEAST, BREACH. I don't have any more information other than they exist, and I don't really know how to address them.

My first question is:

How can I test a site for these vulnerabilities? I would like to be able to reproduce the issue, and test that it's been resolved after I address it.

How do I fix the issues? My first thought goes to security headers, but I haven't found any information on google that supports that.

Any information is helpful - I'm pretty much starting at 0 here.

Server: Ubuntu 18.04 (Apache)
CMS: WordPress 6.2.2
Framework: Laravel
PHP version: 7.3.19

Comment: A quick Google shows that these vulnerabilities are all related to HTTPS/SSL and between 10 and 20 years old. They have nothing to do with WordPress. You would need to speak to your host to find out if their software is vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie

Comment: "How can I test a site for these vulnerabilities?" - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @Rup I actually came across this tool during my initial research. I see a ton of info, but nothing about the specific vulnerabilities above...

Comment: Beast is right there in the list. Lucky13 requires a CBC cipher suite and they're all marked 'weak' by the scanner. But true, Breach isn't covered as it targets HTTP compression not TLS compression.